# Back button closing app even when using FragmentTransaction.addToBackStack()

Tags: android, android-fragments, back-button, back-stack

None of the other questions I have read on stackoverflow have been able to help with my problem. As far as I can tell, I am doing everything correctly.

I have a master/detail flow with fragments.

Upon creation of the main activity, the master fragment is loaded with the following code:

```
    Fragment frag;
    frag = new MainListFragment();//<-- **the master fragment**

    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, frag);
    Log.d("My Debug Bitches", "stack:" + fm.getBackStackEntryCount());
    transaction.commit();
```

The master fragment has a `ListView`; clicking on a list item brings up the details fragment like so:

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(listView, view, position, id);


    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
    SubListFragment frag = new SubListFragment();//<-- **the detail fragment**

    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, frag);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
    fm.executePendingTransactions();
    Log.d("My Debug Bitches", "stack:" + fm.getBackStackEntryCount());

}
```

Now, according to LogCat, the `BackStackEntryCount` **changes from 0 to 1** after I navigate from master fragment to detail fragment: [image]

So why is it that, when I click the back button while in the details fragment, that the app closes instead of returning to the master fragment??????????

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You have to add the [`popBackStack()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#popBackStack%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) call to the [`onBackPressed()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed%28%29) method of the activity.

Ex:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        fragmentManager.popBackStack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: wow thanks. I was operating under the delusion that `onBackPressed()` automatically provides this functionality and only needs to be overridden when special actions are desired.

Comment: @ScottScooterWeidenkopf : Popping a `Fragment` IS a special action. The BACK button was around long before `Fragments` and changing it's default behaviour in the core Android code wouldn't have been a good idea for backward compatibility reasons. Hence the reason you need to handle things yourself.

Comment: The documentation says the opposite!
"Pop fragments off the back stack, with popBackStack() (simulating a Back command by the user)."
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html
Quite disconcerting. It doesn't mention onBackPressed(). Thanks for your solution. I was looking for an automatic way because it feels like a hack.

Comment: It doesn't even mention it in the documentation that's specifically about back navigation with fragments.  In fact it seems to state something that's flat out false: "When there are FragmentTransaction objects on the back stack and the user presses the Back button, the FragmentManager pops the most recent transaction off the back stack and performs the reverse action."  Thanks Google.  And a non-sarcastic thanks to Bobbake4.  http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html#back-fragments

Comment: I did notice recently that this is the case on the newer versions of Android. On the support library version you must add the popbackstack code but on at least Kit Kat the default behavior is to pop the back stack.

Comment: Plus 10. This problem was ruining my life.

Comment: There seems to be different behavior between the normal and the support package. My app worked perfectly without onBackPressed(), but once I move away from the support library I had to add onBackProcessed().

Comment: @VincentNikkelen I have also noticed that. If you look at my comment above it seems that Google may have changed the default behavior on Kit Kat and above. It still may be a good idea to explicitly define the behavior you would like as you don't know what Google may change it to at a later date.

Answer (score 0):

@Bobbake4's answer is awesome, but there is one little problem.
Let's say I have three fragments A, B and C.
A is the main Fragment (the fragment that shows when I launch my app), B and C are  fragments I can navigate to from the navigation drawer or from A.
Now, when I use the back button from B or C, I go back to the previous fragment (A) alright, but the title of the previous fragment (fragment B or C) now shows in the actionBar title of Fragment A. I have to press the back button again to "truly" complete the back navigation (to display the view and correct title for the fragment and returning to)

This is how I solved this problem. Declare these variables.

```
 public static boolean IS_FRAG_A_SHOWN = false;
 public static boolean IS_FRAG_B_SHOWN = false;
 public static boolean IS_FRAG_C_SHOWN = false;
```

In the MainActivity of my app where am handling navigation drawer methods, I have a method `displayView(position)` which handles switching of my fragments.

```
private void displayView(int position) {
    IS_FRAG_A_SHOWN = false;
    IS_FRAG_B_SHOWN = false;
    IS_FRAG_C_SHOWN = false;
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new FragmentA();
            IS_FRAG_A_SHOWN = true;
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new FragmentB();
            IS_FRAG_B_SHOWN = true;
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new FragmentC();
            IS_FRAG_C_SHOWN = true;
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
```

finally, in my `onBackPressed` method, I do this:

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() != 0) {
        fragmentManager.popBackStack();
        if (IS_FRAG_A_SHOWN) { //If we are in fragment A when we press the back button, finish is called to exit
            finish();
        } else  {
            displayView(0); //else, switch to fragment A
        }

    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```