# Retain values in EditTexts of a fragment while returning

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an activity where I have put 5 fragments for signup process. First fragment has two edit texts and a textview. Edit texts are for first and last name and text view takes me to next fragment2. Whenn I come back from frag2 to frag 1, those firstname and lastname values disappears. I have tried storing values in onSavedInstance method with putString method and retrieve it in onCreate method but its not helping. Here is the code...

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if(savedInstanceState==null){

    }
    else{
        firstName=savedInstanceState.getString("firstname");
        lastName=savedInstanceState.getString("lastname");
        fname.setText(firstName);
        lname.setText(lastName);
    }
}

 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag1,container,false);
    fname = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.si_firstname);
    lname = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.si_lastname);
    firstName = fname.getText().toString();
    lastName = lname.getText().toString();
    next1 = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.next1);    


    next1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { //takes to frag2.
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(firstName.isEmpty() || lastName.isEmpty()){
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "no name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else {

                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, secondFragment);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    outState.putString("firstname", firstName);
    outState.putString("lastname", lastName);
}
```

Comment: how do you come back to fragment1, via back button ?

Comment: Yes back button on frag 2...

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, secondFragment);
```

Use

```
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, secondFragment);
```

**Edit**

If this isn't working then you will have to use `addToBackstack` in your transaction, that will surely work. However you will also need to override `onBackPressed` function in Main activity and popbackStack to pop the fragment before returning to the previous one. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23728216/back-button-closing-app-even-when-using-fragmenttransaction-addtobackstack) is how you need to override it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're overwriting the savedInstance data you're getting inside your `onCreate` with the values you're setting in `onCreateView`. Try commenting out the code in your `onCreate` and replacing the top lines inside of your `onCreateView` with:

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag1,container,false);
fname = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.si_firstname);
lname = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.si_lastname);
next1 = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.next1);

if(savedInstanceState != null){ //the data's on the savedinstance
   firstName = savedInstanceState.getString("firstname");
   lastName = savedInstanceState.getString("lastname");
   //restore the editTexts
   fname.setText(firstName);
   lname.setText(lastName);
}else{
   firstName = fname.getText().toString();
   lastName = lname.getText().toString();

   //whatever you want to do on the first run
   //or if the data's not on the savedInstance
}

//whatever else you want to do on every run
```